# Cytoscape JS - Create a node by drag and drop from outside palette

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is there a way to create new nodes by drag & drop something from outside the graph, such as a palette or whatever.
I think there is no such extension, the only one I've found is this one : https://github.com/ayushkr19/cytoscape.js-nodeadd which is 9 years old and use jQuery.

If there is no extension, how can I approach this using event listeners maybe ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found a way, here's my solution ;)

ref

```
const graphRef = useRef<Core>()
```

button for UI

```
<div draggable="true">
    <button>Add toto node</button>
</div>
```

Cytoscape wrapper

```
<div onDrop={(e) => handleCreateNode(e)} onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
  <CytoscapeComponent
    cy={(cy) => (graphRef.current = cy)}
  />
</div>
```

And the key, the function to create a node at the right place

```
const handleCreateNode = (e: DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  if (!graphRef.current) return;

  e.preventDefault();

  const pan = graphRef.current.pan();
  const zoom = graphRef.current.zoom();
  const x = e.nativeEvent.offsetX
  const y = e.nativeEvent.offsetY

  graphRef.current.add({
    data: { id: String(Math.random()), label: addType },
    position: {
      x: (x - pan.x) / zoom,
      y: (y - pan.y) / zoom,
    },
  });
};
```

This is a React working version.

Comment: For graphs that aren't fullscreen, you can use `offsetX` instead of `clientX`

Comment: @teamshortcut I think offset doesn't exist on a div

Comment: But this does and worked like à charmed indeed ;)
const x = e.nativeEvent.offsetX
const y = e.nativeEvent.offsetY